# Http post ionic shows error

Tags: angular, post, ionic-framework, promise, ionic3

I have wrote this code,

#### ServiceProvider.ts

```
postData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var cred = {
      "username": "abc",
      "password": "password",
      "admin_channels": "[channel_abc]"
    };
    var header = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };

    this.http.post(apiUrl + 'api/login', cred, header).subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    }, err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

This way I call to my service provider

```
this.authService.postData().then((result) => {
  this.loading.dismiss();

  alert("full data " + JSON.stringify(result));

}, (err) => {
  this.loading.dismiss();
  alert(JSON.stringify(err)); //SHows ERROR HERE
});
```

It is giving me this error:

> {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}

Where I am making a mistake?

Comment: What is apiUrl? If it is defined outside of the function, you should use this.apiUrl.

Comment: it is defined outside class above to @Injectable()

Comment: Does using this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'api/login', cred, header) solve the issue?

Comment: It shows error when i write this.apiUrl

Comment: It shows the same error as before?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for this?